# Chart Percentage Differences in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

How can I chart year on year percentage change in a reporting services chart?

From my source data (which is a SharePoint 2010 list) I can use the "Previous" function in a table to work out the percentage change over time in years.  I have row groups (the years shown below) and column groups (A, B and C).

```
      A | B | C
-----------------
2010  
2011  3%  4% 5%
2012  2%  3% 1%
```

The formula in the table is (year 2 rate - year 1 rate)/year 1 rate.  The first row is blank because I have an iff function checking if there is a previous row, and to show nothing if that is the case. Otherwise it does the calculation.

I cannot use the previous function in a chart.  How can I graph this?  If this was a normal database I would look to doing something at that level and present the to reporting services, but with a SharePoint list I can not and have to do the grouping and other work in reporting services (2008 R2) itself.

Any ideas?  I am open to presenting the data in another way if that can effectively provide some view of how the data has changed over time in a chart.

Answer (score 0):

To extract another years set of use the `lookupset` function and the `sum` function e.g.

```
=sum(fields!number.value) - sum(lookupset(fields!year.value - 1, fields!year.value, fields!number.value, "dataset")
```

Further reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx

Also the `lookupset` function returns all matched values and the `lookup` function returns the first only.